# How is a SASS error message displayed in the browser?

Tags: sass

In SASS, when there is an error, it shows a message at the top of the page in the browser. A sample of it is in the attached image.

That text is not selectable. It is not an image. It does not appear in View Source. It is not visible in Firebug.

How is that error text being rendered?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @FluffyJack, I investigated and found that a `body:before` is used in the CSS file that contains the syntax error. Github is not being cooperative at the moment, but I traced where the error message is rendered from in SASS to `vendor/sass/lib/sass/error.rb` which contains:

```
body:before {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: "#{header.gsub('"', '\"').gsub("\n", '\\A ')}"; }
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's using a content attribute.

Something like

```
html:before {
  content: "Syntax error..."
}
```

Check the css.

Comment: LOL, you are right. I tested this via a test html file. But, no such text or css :before is in the source. Maybe added via Javascript? (but I cannot find any evidence of that as yet) Any idea why that text is not selectable? Is this "requirement" part of HTML spec?

Comment: No idea why. But CSS content is never selectable. Guess might be part of the CSS spec that it gets treated like that. Maybe you're right with the HTML spec.

Comment: Kinda proud of myself right now, that was a wild guess :D hehe